# Программа не показывает данные в приложении из ObservableCollection ,C#

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, observablecollection

Model

```
namespace MyProject
{
    class WeatherRecord
    {
        public double Temp { get; set; }
    }

    class WeatherVeiwModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        ObservableCollection<WeatherRecord> Forecast { get; set; } = new
            ObservableCollection<WeatherRecord>();

        private int temp;
                   public int Temprature
        {
            get { return temp; }
            set
            {
                temp = value;
                Notify("Temprature");
            }
        }

        private void Notify(string f)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(f));
        }

        public async Task Load()
        {
            HttpClient cli = new HttpClient();
            var res = await cli.GetStringAsync("http://api.wunderground.com/api/07c49dfe95e0b6c8/conditions/q/BY/Gomel.json");
            dynamic x = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res);
            Temprature = x.current_observation.temp_c;

            res = await cli.GetStringAsync("http://api.wunderground.com/api/07c49dfe95e0b6c8/forecast/q/BY/Gomel.json");
            x = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res);
            foreach (var z in x.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday)
            {
                Forecast.Add(new WeatherRecord()
                {
                    Temp = z.high.celsius
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

VM

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        WeatherVeiwModel VM = new WeatherVeiwModel();

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.DataContext = VM;
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            await VM.Load();
        }

    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyProject.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyProject"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
            <TextBlock x:Name="Temp" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="28" Text="{Binding Temprature}" />
            <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Forecast}">
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Temp}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

[Ссылка на API](http://api.wunderground.com/api/07c49dfe95e0b6c8/forecast/q/BY/Gomel.json)

Comment: В чём сам вопрос заключается не могли бы поподорбнее описать, пожалуйста

Comment: прошу прощения, в программе я хочу показать температуру за 3 дня, которые я беру из интернета посредством API формата JSON, для записи я использую observablecollection, однако когда я нажимаю на отладку, данные не отображаются в приложении и я не могу понять почему не отображаются данные после отладки.Ошибок никаких не выдает на удивление

Comment: в вопрос приложите это, пожалуйста. Комментарии чиают не все

Comment: спасибо, просто впервые тут

Comment: А вы не могли бы убрать из кода всё ненужное? Если вопрос про `ObservableCollection`, то `BitmapImage` и загрузка/разбор JSON явно не относятся к теме вопроса. [mcve]

Comment: Пройдите  степ-бай-степ метод Load. Данные точно загружаются с сервиса и попадают в коллекцию ?

Comment: `public MainPage() { this.DataContext = VM; this.InitializeComponent(); }` а если поменять порядок? Сначала `this.InitializeComponent();`, а потом `this.DataContext = VM;`?

Comment: спасибо я учту маленькие недочеты, 
поменял местами dataContext ничего не вышло, 
сама суть проблемы, что я не могу через привязку Binding отобразить данные которые должны были быть записаны в ObservableColl. , так же не могу понять записала ли программа в ObservableColl. данные или нет , так как степ-бай-степ до этого момента у меня все нормально работает, с API данные берет , но когда через foreach я перебираю API  для записи температуры по дням вот тут я не понимаю даже в чем ошибка, делал по примеру с сайта My virtual academy

Comment: и после срабатывания программы у меня не отображаются данные за несколько дней и не выдает никаких ошибок

Answer (score 3):

[image: Пример]

В классе в который вы планируете собирать информацию следует реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
public class WeatherRecord : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private double _Temp;
    public double Temp
    {
        get { return _Temp; }
        set
        {
            _Temp = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Temp));
        }
    }

    private BitmapImage _Image;
    public BitmapImage Image
    {
        get { return _Image; }
        set
        {
            Image = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Image));
        }
    }

    private double _Pressure;
    public double Pressure
    {
        get { return _Pressure; }
        set
        {
            _Pressure = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Pressure));
        }
    }

    private string _Humidity;
    public string Humidity
    {
        get { return _Humidity; }
        set
        {
            _Humidity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Humidity));
        }
    }

    private string _Weather;
    public string Weather
    {
        get { return _Weather; }
        set
        {
            _Weather = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Weather));
        }
    }


    private void OnPropertyChanged(string nameProperty)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameProperty));
    }

}
```

Вьюмодель будет такая, по нажатию на кнопку запускаем метод `ShowForecasts()`

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private const string _ADDRESS_CURRENT = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/07c49dfe95e0b6c8/conditions/q/BY/Gomel.json";
    private const string _ADDRESS_DAYS = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/07c49dfe95e0b6c8/forecast/q/BY/Gomel.json";
    private const string _CONTENT_TYPE = "application/json";
    private const string _JSON_CURRENT = "current_observation.temp_c";
    private const string _JSON_DAYS = "forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday";


    private ObservableCollection<WeatherRecord> _Forecasts;
    public ObservableCollection<WeatherRecord> Forecasts
    {
        get { return _Forecasts; }
        set
        {
            _Forecasts = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Forecasts));
        }
    }

    private int _Temprature;
    public int Temprature
    {
        get { return _Temprature; }
        set
        {
            _Temprature = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Temprature));
        }
    }


    private void OnPropertyChanged(string nameProperty)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameProperty));
    }


    public async Task ShowForecasts()
    {
        string current = await GetForecastsAsync(_ADDRESS_CURRENT);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(current))
        {
            Debug.Write("Чего-то не загрузилась погодка");
            return;
        }

        BuildForecastCurrent(current);

        string days = await GetForecastsAsync(_ADDRESS_DAYS);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(days))
        {
            Debug.Write("Чего-то не загрузилась погодка для дней");
            return;
        }

        BuildForecastDays(days);
    }

    private void BuildForecastCurrent(string current)
    {
        dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(current);

        Temprature = jsonObject.SelectToken(_JSON_CURRENT);
    }

    private void BuildForecastDays(string wundergroundData)
    {
        dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(wundergroundData);

        Forecasts = new ObservableCollection<WeatherRecord>();

        foreach (var day in jsonObject.SelectToken(_JSON_DAYS))
        {
            Forecasts.Add(new WeatherRecord()
            {
                Temp = day.high.celsius
            });

        }
    }

    private async Task<string> GetForecastsAsync(string address)
    {
        string result = String.Empty;

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(_CONTENT_TYPE));

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(address))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```